# Styling <li> with background images in an <ul>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm setting up a footer for a site and using an unordered list with three list items as follows:

```
<ul id="socialnav">
    <li id="facebook"></li>
    <li id="twitter"></li>
    <li id="googleplus"></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to use background images for the list items to display the social media icons and then I would like to apply a hover state to the list item for the button's 'on-state'.  However, my three icons won't appear horizontally in the list.  Here is my css:

```
#socialnav {
display: inline;
line-height: 42px;
}

#facebook {
background-image: url("images/fb.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
list-style-type: none;
height: 42px;
}

#twitter {
background-image: url("images/twt.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
list-style-type: none;
height: 42px;
}

#googleplus {
background-image: url("images/gplus.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
list-style-type: none;
height: 42px;
}
```

Two questions - why is this not working?  And is there a better/easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your `li` elements appear in a horizontal fashion, you can make two changes.

First, remove the `display: inline` from the `ul`:

```
#socialnav {
    line-height: 42px;
}
```

Second, style the `li` elements to float and use `display: block`:

```
#socialnav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Note that the width and border directives were added to allow the elements to appear on the page which the images are unavailable. You can remove them as needed.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GTVbR/).

Comment: no real need to also set `display: block`. When you float an element it will ignore display property. (except IE6)

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably you don't see images because your list-items are empty so they're not wide enough to see images, or the path to the images is incorrect.
2. Use classes instead of id's. So you can re-use the icons again in the same page if needed. Use also `list-style : none` once, applied to `<ul>` element and `background-position: no-repeat; height: 42px;` once, applied to every `<li>`. Another improvement could be using a sprite image, containing all the icons in a single file (so to avoid too many server requests and reduce the overall image size)

Answer (score 1):

For a start I'd make sure your CSS is looking for images in the right place. **The url needs to be relative to the CSS file, not the site root.**

Secondly I'd put a `&nbsp;` in your `<li>` tags to make sure they're not seens as being empty.

The code works otherwise.

```
 #facebook {
     background-image: url("http://www.moifacebook.ru/wp-content/themes/atenta12/sections/branding/facebook.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     list-style-type: none;
     height: 42px;
}  

<ul id="socialnav">
        <li id="facebook">&nbsp;</li>
        <li id="twitter">&nbsp;</li>
        <li id="googleplus">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/yQzDy/

Comment: Yes, that will change when put into production, however, right now I'm linking locally for development purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as below

```
<ul id="socialnav">
<li id="facebook">&nbsp;</li>
<li id="twitter">&nbsp;</li>
<li id="googleplus">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>​
```

Change CSS to

```
#socialnav {
display: inline;
 line-height: 42px;
   }

  #facebook {
  background: url("images/fb.png") no-repeat;
  list-style-type: none;
   height: 42px;
    }

   #twitter {
   background: url("images/twt.png") no-repeat;
  list-style-type: none;
   height: 42px;
   }

 #googleplus {
  background: url("images/gplus.png") no-repeat;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 42px;
  }
```

Comment: Using non-breaking spaces (or a blank gif) for styling purposes only is something bad and wrong

Answer (score 0):

First of all not sure why you are making #socialnav display:inline... that really makes no sense.

Second of all you should place an anchor inside your li's to make these social links clickable. Then you should make those anchors display:block and use them as a way to handle the sizing of the icons.

**Make sure there is some width specified!**

Comment: `li` tags are `block` by default, width should not be required.  Though I suspect that there is some pertinent css missing from the example.